# Java Getter method - How to re-utilize them?

Tags: java, swing

Is it possible to re-use a getter, instead of having to create one for each return value (they are all of the type JPanel.

Here is my class:

```
public class GamePanels {         
    JPanel begin, middle, end;  

public void begin(){            
    begin = new JPanel();  
    begin.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);  
    JLabel beginLabel = new JLabel("Do you want to avoid using much of your brain?");  
    JButton beginYes = new JButton("Yes");  
    JButton beginNo = new JButton("No");  
    begin.add(beginLabel);  
    begin.add(beginYes);  
    begin.add(beginNo);                       
}  
public void middle(){  
    //code here  
}  
public void end(){  
    //code here  
}  


public JPanel getPanel(){  
    return begin;  
}  
public JPanel getPanel1(){  
    return middle;  
}  
public JPanel getPanel2(){  
    return end;  
}  
}
```

This is a snippet from my main class (class used by the actionListener:

```
newButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){  
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){               
            GamePanels g = new GamePanels();   
            g.begin();                            
            container.add("Begin", g.getPanel());  
            cl.show(container, "Begin");  
        }  
    });
```

Instead of creating a huge amount of getters and remembering which getter I need, is there a way to re-use the same one? Like maybe adding a parameter somewhere so it can all go through one getter? Or do I have to write a separate one for each value?

Comment: Maybe renaming your getters will make it easy for you to remember which getter to use. Also three getters does not imply "a huge amount of getters".

Comment: Why don't you just name them something that indicates which panel they are for? Such as: `getBeginPanel()` and `getMiddlePanel()`. Then it is easy to know which is for which.

Comment: @manouti I agree, but I wanted to know before I go all out. I calculated I will probably need around 50+ getters, so I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing a trick before hand

Comment: @forgivenson I will name it something better, above was only a quick example for testing purposes to see if there was an alternative way since I will probably need over 50 getters!

Comment: @gudthing If you have 50+ panels you need to get at different times, I would consider combining them into a data structure of some sort, like a map or list, as is suggested in the answers.

Comment: @forgivenson yeah I'm definitely going to structured them some way, this is why I'm gathering all this information from the guru's on stackoverflow! I like the idea of a Map and I think that would be an efficient way to manage the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to define a getter that returns a specific panel based on a parameter. The way I'd do it in your case (with the little information you have posted) would be to define an enum with the possible states (provided you have a known set of possible states), and associate a panel to each state via a lookup map. E.g. (I didn't try to compile this code, it might contain a few compilation errors):

```
public enum GameState {
    BEGIN, MIDDLE, END;
}

public class GamePanels {
    private Map<GameState, JPanel> lookup = new HashMap<GameState, JPanel> ();
    private JPanel beginPanel;
    private JPanel middlePanel;
    private JPanel endPanel;

    public GamePanels () {
        // Initialize panels

        lookup.put (GameState.BEGIN, beginPanel);
        lookup.put (GameState.MIDDLE, middlePanel);
        lookup.put (GameState.END, endPanel);
    }

    public getPanel (GameState state) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel ();

        if (lookup.containsKey (state)) {
            panel = lookup.get (state);
        }

        return panel;
    }
}
```

Note that while this will work, this might not be the optimal implementation for this kind of problem. This subject would be a better fit for Programmers.SE.

Comment: This is very much the sort of thing that I was looking for! Would you mind explaining to me a little bit more on what enum does? Is that basically how the `getPanel` knows which panel to trigger, due to the relationship it holds in `lookup`? (I will look at Programmers.SE in future, thanks for advice)

Comment: @gudthing An enum is an enumeration of contants. This allows you to allow only a predefined number of values for the `GameState`, as opposed to using an `int` or `String`, which allows other programmers to specify all kind of values, even those you do not support. Please read this [article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) on the enum data type for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I would still use different getters but would name them better, as already mentioned in the comments.

If you insist on a reusable getter then you could map your JPanel's in a map with String's as keys and then get them by name which you could provide to the getter method as an argument.

Comment: that's an interesting way to do it, I will try it out! Thanks

Comment: Your welcome! Laf already provided a similar enough example too.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine them into a single getter, using `switch` cases for the different panels. Note that for the cases, it may prove convenient to use final variables that correspond to each panel, such as the one below (`beginPanelID`) to represent which panel you want.

```
public static final int beginPanelID = 1;

public JPanel getPanel(Integer whichPanel){

   switch(whichPanel){
       case beginPanelID: // aka case 1
          return begin;
       case 2:
          return middle;
       ...
       case X:
          return lastPanel;
       case default: // for any other cases
           return defaultPanel;
    }       
}
```

So when you call `getPanel()`, you more/less tell it which panel you want, and it gives it to you.

Comment: Thanks Mike, thats a very nice way to do it I will have to play around with Maps and Switches and decide which technique is most convenient for my project.